# Blackberry 6.x | PhoneListener.callFailed not called on BB Torch 9800

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm faced with a problem, [PhoneListener.callFailed](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html#callFailed%28int,%20int%29) not called on BB9800.

On BB9780, [PhoneListener.callFailed](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html#callFailed%28int,%20int%29) has been called with [CALL_ERROR_OUTGOING_CALLS_BARRED](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/phone/PhoneListener.html#CALL_ERROR_OUTGOING_CALLS_BARRED).

Both devices have 6.0 Bundle 2342 ( v6.0.0.526, Platform 6.6.0.195)

P.S. I know this is looks like API issue, but I cannot file the bug report for OS lower then 10